# EC2 and AMQP: strange TCP issue under load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amqp, aws-opsworks

Our app is backed by a cluster of EC2 instances. One of them is running RabbitMQ, and all the instances read and write messages from/to the message queues.

It worked perfectly, until yesterday when we had a significant traffic spike. The messaging system started to fail: the services were able to create queues, but they could not write nor read messages.

It started to happen intermittently, then all the time.

I restarted RabbitMQ but it did not help. Rebooted the instances: did not help either. I ended up stopping the full stack, then starting it again. After a while things got back to normal.

From what I could tell (but I am not sure), the problem was the instances failed to communicate with each other (RabbitMQ sends messages other TCP on a specific port).

I am concerned it will happen again since I am not really sure what fixed it. And I am not even sure where to look.

- Is AWS throttling/limiting communications between instances if there is too much traffic going on?
- Is is possible that a security group starts failing (for RabbitMQ to work you need to open the specific TCP port)
- Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs? If RabbitMQ was throttling producers, it should appear on the logs.

Comment: @old_sound Thank you. That was it. A "Disk free space insufficient." warning led to "Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears" status. I had no idea RabbitMQ could do that. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Check this link about RabbitMQ flow control - http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html, maybe the lack of disk space or any other resources is the cause of your problems.

Comment: @zaq178miami Yes. For some reason, the default RabbitMQ setup requires 1000MB of free space... I did not think it would be that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If RabbitMQ was throttling producers, it should appear on the logs. Specially when RabbitMQ decides to throttle publishers in order to prevent running out of memory or disk space. As @zaq178miami points out, see this link: http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html